# How ID's with dashes are treated in JavaScript? (automatically global variable creation)

Tags: javascript

When you create a HTML element and add an ID to it, like:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

It will be automatically available in Javascript as the variable `test` without the need to use `document.getElementById("test")`.

What I want to know is what happens when you create an ID with dashes, like:

```
<div id="test-one"></div>
```

This element will still be available in Javascript through some variable or the variable won't be created? I tried to check the value of `test-one` and `testOne` but none of them contains something.

EDIT

I think most of people are misunderstanding the question. I know that creating a variable with dashes is perfect valid.

This is the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/jn33bgkd/

You don't need to use `document.getElementById` because Javascript creates global variables automatically with the same names of the IDs (i know it's a bad practice to use those, I just wanna know what's the behavior)
But these global variables aren't created if the ID has a dash. The question is if the global variable of the element that has an ID with dash is really not created or is created with a differente name.

Comment: have you tested it... what is the result

Comment: I know the use of dashes is valid, what i want to know if the global variable containing the HTML element of the same name of the id will still be created.

Comment: FYI, it's generally considered a poor strategy to use those auto-created global variables in the first place because it's way too easy for some other Javascript to end up conflicting with them.  Just use `document.getElementById("test-one")` and forget about the auto-created globals.

Comment: var myDiv = $("#test-one") is valid or getElementById will work also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7dytbg2e/1/ - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id

Comment: Right jfriend00... I just wanna know what's the behavior

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7dytbg2e/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, `test-one` is an expression containing two identifiers, `test` and `one`, and the `-` operator; essentially, an arithmetic subtraction between two unrelated variables. Because of this, writing `test-one` literally won't work.

However the element is still accessible using an indexer, i.e. `window['test-one']`.

```js
window['test-one'].innerHTML = 'Test';
```

```html
<div id="test-one"></div>
```

Note that an element with an ID of "test-one" is *never* reflected as the global `testOne`, as it would otherwise create a conflict with an element with an ID of "testOne".

This behavior was originally non-standard, having its roots in IE legacy. It is now documented [in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) and [in the HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), though the former considers it non-normative. Presumably this was done to facilitate cross-browser compatibility with legacy documents.

Related question: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: yeah thanks this is exacly the answer i wanted. So the global variable is still there but only acessible by the window object.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is called "inflection", this is when strings such as "test-one" are interpreted as "testOne".

Generally there are some languages that take this approach (e.g.: Ruby); however it's generally not a great approach as it requires libraries with rules to define the inflection, and the variables are not always standardised.

Remember, you can always shortcut a method:

```
var x = document.getElementById;
var testOne = x("test-one");
```

Have you considered using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)?

Comment: "Shortcutting" a method rarely works like that; if you assign a method to a variable, you end up with a function that no longer has the right idea of `this`. You'd do better to say `var x = document.getElementById.bind(document);` or the like.